# In phonepe payment gateway implement on website (codeigniter) "paymentInstrument type" I'm passing is "PAY_PAGE" but in resonse getting "UPI_INTENT"

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, phonepe

I am trying to implement phonepe payment gateway on website using codeigniter framework..till yesterday the test response was coming r8 but suddenly the response has changed and its not working.

My CURL data:

```
                $con = json_decode($json);
                $con->merchantId = "PGTESTPAYUAT"; //my merchant id for testing 
                $con->merchantTransactionId = "ABCD12345";
                $con->merchantUserId = "A123R";
                $con->amount = 10000;  //100 rupees
                $con->redirectUrl = "https://abc.in/after_payment";
                $con->callbackUrl = "https://abc.in/webhook";
                $con->mobileNumber = "9876543210";
                $con->paymentInstrument->type = "PAY_PAGE";

                $encode = json_encode($con);
                $encoded = base64_encode($encode);
                $salt_key = "099eb0cd-02cf-4e2a-8aca-3e6c6aff0399"; //test salt key
                $salt_index = 1; //key index 1
                $string = $encoded . "/pg/v1/pay" . $salt_key;
                $sha256 = hash("sha256", $string);
                $final_x_header = $sha256 . '###' . $salt_index;
                $request_json = '{
    "request":"ewogICJtZXJjaGFudElkIjogIk1FUkNIQU5UVUFUIiwKICAibWVyY2hhbnRUcmFuc2FjdGlvbklkIjogIk1UNzg1MDU5MDA2ODE4ODEwNCIsCiAgIm1lcmNoYW50VXNlcklkIjogIk1VSUQxMjMiLAogICJhbW91bnQiOiAxMDAwMCwKICAicmVkaXJlY3RVcmwiOiAiaHR0cHM6Ly93ZWJob29rLnNpdGUvcmVkaXJlY3QtdXJsIiwKICAicmVkaXJlY3RNb2RlIjogIlBPU1QiLAogICJjYWxsYmFja1VybCI6ICJodHRwczovL3dlYmhvb2suc2l0ZS9jYWxsYmFjay11cmwiLAogICJtb2JpbGVOdW1iZXIiOiAiOTk5OTk5OTk5OSIsCiAgInBheW1lbnRJbnN0cnVtZW50IjogewogICAgInR5cGUiOiAiUEFZX1BBR0UiCiAgfQp9"
}';
                $request_json_decode = json_decode($request_json);
                $request_json_decode->request = $encoded;
                $request = json_encode($request_json_decode);

                $curl = curl_init();

                curl_setopt_array($curl, [
                    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api-preprod.phonepe.com/apis/merchant-simulator/pg/v1/pay",
                    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
                    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
                    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
                    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $request,
                    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
                        "Content-Type: application/json",
                        "X-VERIFY: " . $final_x_header,
                        "accept: application/json"
                    ],
                ]);

                $response = curl_exec($curl);
                $err = curl_error($curl);

                curl_close($curl);

                if ($err) {
                    echo "Error #:" . $err;
                } else {
                    $res = json_decode($response);
                    pr($res);
                    if ($res->code == 'PAYMENT_INITIATED') {
                        redirect($res->data->instrumentResponse->redirectInfo->url);
                    } else {
                        redirect('web/checkout');
                    }
                }
```

the response i am getting from phonepe is: (i have json_decode the response)

```
stdClass Object
(
    [success] => 1
    [code] => PAYMENT_INITIATED
    [message] => Payment Initiated
    [data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [merchantId] => PGTESTPAYUAT
            [merchantTransactionId] => AM434928276
            [instrumentResponse] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [type] => UPI_INTENT //you can clearly see i had passed PAY_PAGE but got UPI_INTENT in respose
                    [intentUrl] => ppesim://pay?pa=PGTESTPAYUAT@ybl&pn=MERCHANT&am=39750&mam=39750&tr=AM434928276&tn=Payment%20for%20AM434928276&mc=5311&mode=04&purpose=00&utm_campaign=B2B_PG&utm_medium=PGTESTPAYUAT&utm_source=AM434928276&mcbs=null
                )

        )

)
```

Yesterday I had a successfull payment but today the entire resonse from phonepe has changed automatically:

This is from successfull test payment

```
$jayParsedAry = [
   "success" => true, 
   "code" => "PAYMENT_SUCCESS", 
   "message" => "Your payment is successful.", 
   "data" => [
         "merchantId" => "PGTESTPAYUAT", 
         "merchantTransactionId" => "74TSELJW6NP2R1GMYDIA", 
         "transactionId" => "T2304271119337956718162", 
         "amount" => 10000, 
         "state" => "COMPLETED", 
         "responseCode" => "PAYMENT_SUCCESS", 
         "paymentInstrument" => [
            "type" => "NETBANKING", 
            "pgTransactionId" => "1995464773", 
            "pgServiceTransactionId" => "PG2212291607083344934300", 
            "bankTransactionId" => null, 
            "bankId" => "null" 
         ] 
      ] 
];
```

I need help in this..is it my side problem or phonepe test apis not working properly.. I have no idea..

I tried Pay API:  https://developer.phonepe.com/v1/reference/pay-api#pay-request-for-web-flow

As my reference but sometimes here also working sometimes internal error (500,502 etc)

Comment: `$con = json_decode($json);` What is the content of the $json variable? 
Consider reviewing your question and breaking it down so it's easier to understand.